# Getting youtube links from span tags. BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, youtube

Im trying to find a way to collect embedded youtube links in BeautifulSoup. Here is an example piece of html.

```
<span data-s9e-mediaembed="youtube"><span><span data-s9e-mediaembed-iframe='["allowfullscreen","","scrolling","no","style","background:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-OQ2mQRB9E4/hqdefault.jpg) 50% 50% / cover","src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/-OQ2mQRB9E4"]' style="background:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-OQ2mQRB9E4/hqdefault.jpg) 50% 50% / cover"></span></span></span>
```

How do I isolate span tags with youtube links in and then parse out the youtube links?

I have tried to isolate spans with youtube links as below but it still prints them all.

```
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, 'html.parser')

vids = soup.find_all("span")

videolist=[]

for i in range (0,len(vids)):

    if vids[i].find("www.youtube.com") != -1:
        videolist.append(vids[i])


for i in videolist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: could you include `url`

Answer (score 0):

What if you use regex to find all the hrefs containing *YouTube* in them

```
import re

r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, 'html.parser')

vids = soup.find_all('span', string=re.compile('youtube')

for a in vids:
    print(a['href'])
```